# Comparing duplicate rows in one table, and returning values in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare rows in the same table of a query and return results of id's matching records in another table.

Here is an example of the first table:

```
id    checkin     checkout 
1     01/15/13    01/31/13   
1     01/31/13    05/20/13
2     01/15/13    05/20/13
3     01/15/13    01/19/13
3     01/19/13    05/20/13
4     01/15/13    02/22/13
5     01/15/13    03/01/13
```

I want to only get records in this table of id's that have no matching record after today's date.  So ID's 1 and 3 would not be returned because the second record checkout date is after today's date.  I then want to match those id's with the a record in another table and return values from that second table.

Example second table:

```
id    address     zip
1     abc         98734
2     uvx         12345
3     ;alksdf     12347
4     bhg         34567
5     ;alkjdf     56789
```

So in this case I would return the address and zip of id 4 and 5.

Comment: You do know how to join tables right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM table2 
 WHERE table2.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT table1.id
                         FROM table1
                         WHERE table1.checkin > sysdate OR
                           table1.checkout > sysdate) AND
 table2.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT table1.id
               FROM table1)
```

Edited to exclude those with dates in the future as well as make sure there is a corresponding record

Comment: Might want to read the question again, the part about no matching records after today's date?

Comment: Won't this return every record before sysdate and not only those that don't have another record after sysdate?

Comment: @trueinViso try that, checks to see if an id has a record in the future, then uses that as a blacklist and then checks to see that a record exists for the address in table1.

Comment: That worked, thanks very much for the help, banged my head for two days on this :/

Answer (score 2):

to get only those records from today or earlier, do this:

```
where checkout <= trunc(sysdate)
```

**Edit starts here**

to exclude records with checkout dates in the future, do this:

```
where not exists
(select 1 record
from yourTable t2
where checkout > trunc(sysdate + 1)
and t2.id = yourTable.id
)
```

Comment: I don't want those records if that id has another record with a checkout after sysdate

Comment: This seems like it would work, but it doesn't.  If I add this statement to the where clause it will not return any records because there exists one record with a checkout after today's date.  Maybe I need to do some kind of inner join?  I am not very proficient with SQL.